# Not able to find KeyTool class in 1.7 java for AIX

Tags: java, aix

I am trying to sign a jar using JarSigner API using java 1.7. This works in Linux and Windows machines but fails in AIX machines with classnotfound exception (for class "sun.security.tools.KeyTool").

I am also not able to find the jar for the class "com.ibm.crypto.tools.KeyTool" which IBM says is the alternative.

Comment: Hello, how are you important those packages into your java runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IBM/Java6, there is a `$JRE_HOME/lib/rt.jar(sun/security/tools/JarSigner.class)` and a `$JRE_HOME/lib/ext/ibmjceprovider(com/ibm/crypto/tools/KeyTool.class)`

In IBM/Java7, there is `$JDK_HOME/lib/tools.jar(sun/security/tools/JarSigner.class)` and `$JRE_HOME/lib/ext/ibmjceprovider(com/ibm/crypto/tools/KeyTool.class)`.

You can add this 'tools.jar' to the `CLASSPATH`.

Mind you, in IBM/Java8 there is no `sun/security/tools/JarSigner.class` in `$JDK_HOME/lib/tools.jar`, but there is `sun/security/tools/jarsigner/Main.class`.